# Typescript error in `Array.reduce()` used inside JSX with JSX as a return value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I have this piece of code (simplified for brevity):

```tsx
function getText(item: {id: number, value: string}[]) {
    return (
        <span>
            {item.map(({ value }) => <>{value}</>)
                .reduce((p, c, i) => [p, <span key={i} className="syntax-operator">, </span>, c])
            }
        </span>
    );
}
```

And TypeScript is complaining about the return value from the `reduce()` function, saying:

```
Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, keyts(2739)
lib.es5.d.ts(1459, 24): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.
```

[image: Code snippet with red underline showing the error]

And I have absolutely no idea how to fix it. I tried messing with the types etc, but nothing worked. At first I just ignored the line with a comment, because the code otherwise works fine. But this is a code for a library and when I build it and try to use it in a project, the output is messed up, so the function must've got broke during compilation due to not being "correct" TypeScript.

How the output should look like (looks before compile) vs how it looks when using the package (after building):

[image: Before and after comparison]

**Anyone knows how to "correctly" get rid of the error?**

Comment: Did you tried React.ReactNode[]

Comment: something like .reduce((p, c, i) => [p, <span key={i} className="syntax-operator">, </span>, c] as React.ReactNode[])

Comment: Nope, still complaining `Type 'ReactNode[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, keyts(2739)`

Comment: If you return a fragment, you can avoid nested arrays: `<>{p}<span key={i} className="syntax-operator">, </span>{value}</>`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a fragment for each text value: `string`s are `ReactNode`s, so you can include them as bare children within the `<span>`. I've included an example.

What's happening below is that the first item's `value` is appended to an array, then each subsequent item's `value` is appended following a comma within a span element, forming a list infixed by commas.

> Ref: [`Array.prototype[@@iterator]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator)

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMAiB5AsnAMyghDgCIpUMBaAExIHo0AbYJAOxjIG4AoX0JFhwA3rzhwYATzBJEVGAFFmSEBxgAacZJlzk6GADkItJFokBlGFGAZcJs7wC+hYqQoKe-abLgBJGFU4AF5RbWBaAC44dgBXEAAjJCg+CQA3FGZYpGiAZ2tgdgBzPic+XgJY9gxgCHZ-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)

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
.syntax-operator { background-color: red; color: white; }
```

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/standalone@7.20.15/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset("tsx", {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets["typescript"], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

import {type ReactElement, type ReactNode} from "react";

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules
const {StrictMode} = React;

type Item = {
  id: number;
  value: string;
};

function ItemsAsText ({items}: { items: readonly Item[] }): ReactElement {
  const iter = items[Symbol.iterator]();
  const firstResult = iter.next();
  if (firstResult.done) return (<span></span>);

  const results: ReactNode[] = [firstResult.value.value];

  for (const {id, value} of iter) {
    results.push((<span key={id} className="syntax-operator">, </span>), value);
  }

  return (<span>{results}</span>);
}

const items: Item[] = [
  {id: 1, value: "foo"},
  {id: 2, value: "bar"},
  {id: 3, value: "baz"},
];

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!);

reactRoot.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <ItemsAsText items={items} />
  </StrictMode>
);

</script>
```

Comment: Well, this works, but it completely redoes the code, ignoring the question of why it shows error in the reduce function.